# Expectation of Pearson Chi-square divergence

Tags: statistics

Following the highly-cited paper, "Estimation of Entropy and Mutual Information" (Liam Paninski, link at the end), it is mentioned that the expectation of Pearson's chi-square functional (divergence) equals to,

\begin{equation*}
E_{p}\left[ \chi ^{2}( p_{N,i} ;p)\right] =\frac{|supp( p) |-1}{N}
\end{equation*}

Where |supp(p)| denotes the support of p (i.e. non-zero discrete probabilities), N denotes the number of samples used to estimate the true (discrete) probability, denoted by p.

However, I cant seem to derive this by myself nor I can find this derivation elsewhere. Is it a mistake?

Edit: attached link:
[https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~binyu/summer08/L2P2.pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebinyu/summer08/L2P2.pdf)